# Papyrus UML: add a type to a property using a Profile (Metamodel Extension)

Tags: eclipse, uml, metamodel, papyrus

I'm defining a profile using *Papyrus UML* in *Eclipse*. I extended metaclass "Class" and "Property" with several Stereotype classes. I can see new Stereotypes in my actual model correctly.
I want to do the same defining my own types in my profile to use them for properties inside classes in my model.

Example: i want to have a property in a class with the type HashMap that is not defined inside basic *Java Type*. I can define a `<<Primitive Type>>` class in my profile naming it "HashMap" but it's not clear to me which UML metaclass I need to extend.

Please provide me a step by step example of profile definition if you have time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend existing UML metaclass to create new type. In UML metamodel, it is defined that an attribute (a `Property`) is linked to a `Type` by the reference `type`. A `Type` that can be attached to a property can be an `Inteface/Class/PrimitiveType...` **instance**. Actually, part of the UML basic types are just `PrimitiveType` instances defined in an other model which is imported (look for `packageImport` in your UML model XMI).

When you set the type of a `Property` to `Integer`, you set the type of your `Property` instance to the `PrimitiveType` instance named `Integer`. So if you want a `HashMap` type, you just have to create an instance of `PrimitiveType` named `HashMap` (as you have done) and that's all.

However, as you are "binding" your model to Java, I suspect that you will probably want to model generic types (`HashMap<String, Integer>` for example). To do that, you will have to handle UML templates.

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html

In that case, you will have to create a templateable `Class` with two formal parameters named `HashMap` and to bind it in order to produce the bound type. Then, you will be able to use the bound type as type for a `Property` instance (no need for UML metamodel extension either).

*Note*: 
`PrimitiveType` is a UML metaclass. You can extend it using *stereotype* (let's say `A` here) in order to create a more refined `PrimitiveType` metaclass. If you do this, in your UML model, you will be able to create `A` instances, but you will not be abe to use `A` as a `Property` type. The only objects you will be able to use will be the created `A` instances.